# Create/embed Firefox/Chrome base browser in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, firefox, embed

Im creating a freeware application (long live the free community) and I'm trying to add various features that might drive people to use the application such as implementing whatsapp web https://web.whatsapp.com/ into the app so that the user will always have an "always on top" window with their chats rather than everytime having to switch tabs if they're multitasking on their browser.

The problem i am having is that the built in Browser control with VS 2013 does not work with whatsapp web and i get the option to use supported browsers like firefox...chrome...safari.

Is there anyway to make a **VB.NET** application open an actual chrome/firefox based browser within itself?

I found an article on Gecko Browser...I am not sure if web.whatsapp.com would see this as a firefox browser: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?692005-Mozilla-Firefox-Gecko-Xulrunner-in-VB-NET-%28versions-14-and-up%29

Help appreciated.

Comment: yes i already stated that i tried the web control but the website does not support it

Comment: The **first** Google result for "embed chrome in .net": http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/611755/Embed-Chrome-or-firefox-Browser-in-Csharp-net-Form

Comment: ^thanks for this i saw the link i had in my original post there so you verified that yes it would be recognized as a non-IE browser. Thanks.